# WearableCalendarContract query doesn't return recurring events

Tags: android, wear-os, android-calendar

I'm creating a watchface for Android Wear which will display calendar events. Based on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/information.html) (and the `WatchFace` sample provided in the SDK), I managed to query the next events for the day, and display them on my watchface (below is the code I use to query the events).

The problem is that recurring events are not returned in the cursor, and thus are not displayed on the watch face. Is there any parameter to add in the query to get recurring events ?

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, // 0
        CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, // 1
        CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, // 2
        CalendarContract.Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, // 3
};

protected List<SpiralEvent> queryEvents() {
    // event is a custom POJO object 
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Uri.Builder builder = WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, begin);
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, begin + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

    final Cursor cursor = mService.getContentResolver()
            .query(builder.build(),
                    PROJECTION,
                    null, // selection (all)
                    null, // selection args
                    null); // order

    // get the start and end time, and the color
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long start = cursor.getLong(1);
        long end = cursor.getLong(2);
        int color = cursor.getInt(3);
        events.add(new Event(start, end, color));
    }

    cursor.close();

    return events;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN` instead of `CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART`; thus, you can change the `PROJECTION` to:

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, // 0
        CalendarContract.Events.BEGIN, // 1
        CalendarContract.Events.END, // 2
        CalendarContract.Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, // 3
};
```

The reason is that:

- `Events.DTSTART` returns start time of the original created event. Note that this event is often in the past; thus, it's filtered out.
- `Events.BEGIN` returns start time of each instance of the event.

Check out source in [CalendarEvent.java](https://github.com/mtrung/android-WatchFace/blob/feature/wearable_calendar/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/calendar/CalendarEvent.java) from my github sample project https://github.com/mtrung/android-WatchFace.