# Android Wear 2.0 - retrieve calendar color from iOS Apple Calendar

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0, calendarcontract

I have an Android Wear app that fetches calendar events via `WearableCalendarContract`. It works great when paired with Android phones, but I recently discovered a bug when pairing with an iOS device using the Apple Calendar, in that it would not fetch event colors.

After some investigation, it looks to me like the Apple Calendar doesn't let users give individual calendar events different colors - however, it does let them create different *calendars,* each with their own individual color. Problem is, my `WearableCalendarContract` query doesn't seem to fetch the calendar colors either.

Is there a solution to this issue, or am I just going to have to set a default color if no color is found?

Code is below. Thanks!

```
final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Uri.Builder builder = WearableCalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

final String[] PROJECTION = {
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, // 0
        CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN, // 1
        CalendarContract.Instances.END, // 2
        CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, // 3
        CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, // 4
        CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, // 5
        CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_COLOR, // 6
        CalendarContract.Events.DISPLAY_COLOR // 7
};

final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
        .query(builder.build(),
                PROJECTION,
                null,  // selection (all)
                null,  // selection args
                null); // order
```

Comment: I don't see any error with your code as compared in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565075/wearablecalendarcontract-query-doesnt-return-recurring-events). There are going to be a lot of features you can’t use on Android Wear with an iOS device when compared to an Android device. If you think this is a bug, you can file a report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190923&template=841312).